# Return Alternating Letters With the Same Length From two Strings

Tags: python, string

there was a similar question asked on here but they wanted the remaining letters returned if one word was longer. I'm trying to return the same number of characters for both strings.

Here's my code:

```
def one_each(st, dum):
    total = ""

    for i in (st, dm):
        total += i
    return total
x = one_each("bofa", "BOFAAAA")
print(x)
```

It doesn't work but I'm trying to get this desired output:

```
>>>bBoOfFaA
```

How would I go about solving this? Thank you!

Comment: are you trying to combine 2 words alternatively? Could you give more examples of your desired output to make it clear?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do that. For example, if I have "abcdefghij" and "ABCD", it should return "aAbBcCdD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.join` with `zip` is possible, since `zip` only iterates pairwise up to the *shortest* iterable. You can combine with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to flatten an iterable of tuples:

```
from itertools import chain

def one_each(st, dum):
    return ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(st, dum)))

x = one_each("bofa", "BOFAAAA")

print(x)

bBoOfFaA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this

```
s1 = "abc"
s2 = "123"
ret = "".join(a+b for a,b in zip(s1, s2))
print (ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short way of doing it.

```
def one_each(short, long):
    if len(short) > len(long):
        short, long = long, short # Swap if the input is in incorrect order

    index = 0
    new_string = ""
    for character in short:
        new_string += character + long[index]
        index += 1

    return new_string            

x = one_each("bofa", "BOFAAAA") # returns bBoOfFaA
print(x)
```

It might show wrong results when you enter `x = one_each("abcdefghij", "ABCD")` i.e when the small letters are longer than capital letters, but that can be easily fixed if you alter the `case` of each letter of the output.

Comment: What do you mean by altering the case?

Comment: For your second input it'll return `AaBbCcDd` which is not what you expect I presume. So you can swap the case of each letter and you'll get your output. `aAbBcCdD`